# Angular elements without injector?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am experimenting with Angular's custom elements and trying to avoid using Angular's dependency injection

```
const MyElementElement = createCustomElement(MyElementComponent, { injector });
customElements.define('my-element', MyElementElement);
```

However I am unable to create a custom element without passing in the injector

```
createCustomElement(MyElementComponent)
```

Is there a way to use the custom element without using Angular's dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an empty injector

```js
createCustomElement(MyElementComponent, Injector.create({ providers: [] }));
```

Comment: Do you have an example where this works? I'm getting a stack trace when I try it.